# Reversing a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, function, logic

I have just started learning c++ and I was trying to create a simple program using functions to reverse a string but this was my attempts and it doesn't appear to be working. It just outputs the string the right way around. Just to clarify I am not looking for an inbuilt function or something like that that does it for me but where the errors are in my logic. If there is a function for it though I would be interested to know. Thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// A program to practice creating and calling a function to reverse a string


using namespace std;



//declaring the function before use
string reverseString(const string& input,string& output);



//main function
int main()
{
    string userInputStr;

    cout << "Please enter a string to be reversed: ";
    getline(cin,userInputStr);
    string reversedString = userInputStr;
    reverseString(userInputStr, reversedString);

    cout << userInputStr << " reversed is " << reversedString;

    return 0;
}

string reverseString(const string& input, string& output)
{
    char characterInString;
    int counter;
    int lengthOfString = input.length();


    for (counter = 0; counter >= lengthOfString; counter++)
    {
        characterInString = input[(lengthOfString - counter)];
        output = output + characterInString;
    }
    return output;


}
```

Thanks for everyone who helped. For those who are interested the updated code that I have managed to fix is below.I know there are simpler ways of doing it which I am looking into but I have only been learning for a couple of days so this is just using what I currently understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// A program to practice creating and calling a function to reverse a string


using namespace std;



//declaring the function before use
string reverseString(const string& input,string& output);



//main function
int main()
{
    string userInputStr;

    cout << "Please enter a string to be reversed: ";
    getline(cin,userInputStr);
    string reversedString = "";
    reverseString(userInputStr, reversedString);

    cout << userInputStr << " reversed is " << reversedString << endl;

    return 0;
}

string reverseString(const string& input, string& output)
{
    char characterInString;
    int counter;
    int lengthOfString = input.length();


    for (counter = 0; counter < lengthOfString +1; counter++)
    {
        characterInString = input[(lengthOfString - counter)];
        output = output + characterInString;
    }
    return output;


}
```

Comment: To begin with, change `counter >= lengthOfString` to `counter < lengthOfString`.

Comment: @barakmanos I tried that but it doesn't seem to change what is output. Sorry but thanks for your help.

Comment: Even after you fix the indices, what do you think `output = output + characterInString;` will do, given the initial value of `output`?

Comment: @juanchopanza I was hoping that it would add each of the characters to the string called output... is that not what happens?

Comment: @JoeRickard And that won't reverse the string, because you have set `output` to the same as the input string. Anyway, there's no need for all this inefficient complication (see my answer.)

Comment: @Thank you for your help. I have removed the part where i assign a value to 'output' before the function. I have looked at your answer as well i will try that but i was just trying to learn some logic by giving myself a logic problem to try and solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop

```
for (counter = 0; counter >= lengthOfString; counter++)
{
    characterInString = input[(lengthOfString - counter)];
    output = output + characterInString;
}
```

there are several errors.

The first one is the loop will never iterate except the case when string input is empty and consequently its length is equal to zero. Only in this case condition

```
counter >= lengthOfString
```

will be evaluated to true.

The second problem is that index evaluated like

```
(lengthOfString - counter)
```

will be outside the valid range of indices when counter is equal to 0.

And at last you already initialized output with input string when called this function

```
string reversedString = userInputStr;
reverseString(userInputStr, reversedString);
```

It would be better to declare the function the following way

```
string reverseString( const string& input );
```

and it could be defined like

```
string reverseString( const string& input )
{
    return std::string( input.rbegin(), input.rend() );
}
```

In main the function would be called like

```
string reversedString = reverseString(userInputStr );
```

If you want to write the function without using the reverse iterators then you could write it like

```
string reverseString( const string& input )
{
    std::string output;
    auto n = input.size();
    output.reserve( n );

    while ( n != 0 ) 
    {
        output += input[--n];
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but would you mind explaining why when counter is equal to 0 it will be outside the range of indicies?
Thanks for the rest btw. It was very useful

Comment: @Joe Rickard If  lengthOfString is defined like int lengthOfString = input.length(); then the valid range of indices will be 0 : lengthOfString - 1.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I think I had misunderstood what the 'input.length()' gave as an output.

Comment: @Joe Rickard  I updated my post because the last function realization was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at that last part again and realized how simple it was. I'm annoyed I didn't think of doing it like that to start with. I think I over complicated it a bit!

Comment: Sorry but in the last part. How can it return output if output is not one of the parameters in the function?

Comment: @Joe Rickard  output is defined as a local variable of the function. After it is built as required its copy is returned in statement return output; In main you have to write  string reversedString = reverseString(userInputStr );

Comment: Oh yeah. Of course. Sorry for asking such stupid questions. I'm quite new to this!

Comment: Sorry but one last thing. What does the output.reserve( n ); do?

Comment: @Joe Rickard  You could write the function without this statement. But in this case almost each time when a new character is added to the string in statement output += input[--n]; when the memory were reallocated that accomodate the new character in the string. member function reserve allows to reserve memory beforehand that after that the memory would not be reallocated when a new character is added.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. You have been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Learning C++ is also about learning what the language and standard library can do for you. For example, learning that a string can be built from two iterators, and that reverse iterators exist:

```
string reversedString(userInputStr.rbegin(), userIntput.rend());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop must start from 1 :

```
for (counter = 1; counter <= lengthOfString; counter++)
{
    characterInString = input[(lengthOfString - counter)];
    output = output + characterInString;
}
```

Also you had the wrong character there : '>' instead of '<'. I also don't know why you set the output string equal to the input string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// A program to practice creating and calling a function to reverse a string


using namespace std;



//declaring the function before use
string reverseString(const string& input,string& output);



//main function
int main()
{
    string userInputStr;

    cout << "Please enter a string to be reversed: ";
    getline(cin,userInputStr);
    string reversedString = "";
    reverseString(userInputStr,reversedString);

    cout << userInputStr << " reversed is " << reversedString;

    return 0;
}

string reverseString(const string& input, string& output)
{
    char characterInString;
    int counter;
    int lengthOfString = input.length();


    for (counter = 1; counter <= lengthOfString; counter++)
    {
        characterInString = input[(lengthOfString - counter)];
        output = output + characterInString;
    }
    return output;


}
```

Here's ideone to provide results : http://ideone.com/47A3y1

Comment: This still won't reverse the string.

Comment: @Chris I have tried that but it doesn't do anything to the output.

Comment: @juanchopanza why are you saying that?

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry. I didn't see the bit belor. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

1 - The `output` contains text when you start your reversal. You probably want to access the elements in `output` along the lines of

```
output[counter] = input[opposite];
```

in addition to fixing the loop condition.

2 - a reasonable way to implement your function using the string type could be.

```
std::string reverse(const std::string& in){
     return std::string(in.rbegin(), in.rend());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I haven't yet learned about some of the parts in your examples though but i will do some looking into it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`for (counter = 0; counter >= lengthOfString; counter++)`

This creates a loop which runs when counter is greater than or equal to the length of the string which, as counter initially equals 0, means that this never runs.

The reason that making `counter < lengthOfString` won't work for you either is because `.length()` returns the number of characters in the string. Therefore a string of 5 characters returns 5, with valid indexes of 0-4. So you need to start looking at `lengthOfString-counter-1` to ensure that when `counter=0` you are truly looking at the last character.

You actually may be copying the NULL character at the end of the string with your current code, which would mean that the first character of your return string is `\0` and that is why the string looks empty.